# An application is not working correctly after Java update from 6.21 to 6.31

Tags: java, flash

We have an application which is talking with Flash clients through sockets. The messages are in XML and not too long, up to 1000 chars.

After the update the messages aren't received correctly at the client side - one byte is missing at the end. The first message is correct, the byte is missing from the end of the second message and the Flash stops because of the parse error.

The application is running on Linux in the production, but I was able to replicate the error in my development environment in Windows.

There are two classes used for the communication:

```
<a href="http://pastebin.com/3dd2Jzsq">WrappedInputStream</a>
```

and

```
<a href="http://pastebin.com/hwVwNe4A">WrappedOutputStream</a>
```

I can modify the Java source, but I'm not able to modify the Flash client.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue after the Java update? Is there a way how to fix it?

Comment: So WrappedOutputStream is the same as a BufferedOutputStream except it sends a 0 and flush() when close() is called? And WrappedInputStream is a BufferedInputStream which skips to 0 when close() is called.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Unfortunately the communication part of the application wasn't made by me. Anyway it's been working well until the update.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, it doesn't do any such thing. The JavaDoc says what it does, though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you be more specific? How does it differ? I have read the Javadoc and the code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Citing the Javadoc: "The packet consists of a header and payload. The header is two bytes of a single unsigned short (written in network order) that specifies the length of bytes in the payload. A header value of 0 indicates that the stream is 'closed'.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And in which method in WrappedOutputStream (see the WrappedInputStream link) does this happen? ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey He he, I have no idea :) But the WrappedInputStream expects it, so I suppose it is left to the client of `WrappedOutputStream`. Otherwise this would always break. BTW there is no mention of writing a 0 in the code, either.

Comment: Well, I can see exactly what was sent and what was received. On the Java side I have a log and on the flash side I have Flashbug. The difference is that the last ">" character from the xml is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I would write some unit tests where you are using a ByteArrayInputStream and a ByteArrayOutputStream and/or PipedInputStream + PipedOutputStream and try to simulate the problem.

i.e. if this really is a Java problem, you should be able to write a self contained test which fails (based on what you have seen fail with flash)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make sure that the `WrappedOutputStream` is being closed properly. Since the purpose of this stream is to send some data without closing the parent stream, there may have been some misunderstanding on the part of the developer, so the stream did not get closed.